# Given value p, return last element of sequence < p - Fortran

Tags: while-loop, fortran, sequence, fortran77

I have a sequence of numbers as follows:

1 , 1, 5, 13, 41, 121, 365, ....

The first two values are:

N(1) = 1 and N(2) = 1

As from 3rd value, N(i) = 2*N(i-1) + 3*N(i-2)

The issue I am facing with is: If I give an argument of p, it should return me the last values of the sequence < p (Using fortran77).

For instance, if p = 90, it should return the value 41.

Comment: How is `len` or `append` not native python?

Comment: Sorry, I would later need to reciprocate the program into fortran and unfortunately fortran do not have those functions.

Comment: Then why bother writing it in python at all?

Comment: you need to know the length of your sequence in order to iterate through it using a while loop. If you don't you'll get out of the array boundaries unless you _know_ there will _always_ be a value < p in your array.

Comment: I would reccomend getting rid of the python tag and adding a fortran77 (or equivalent) instead. Or just ask a new question

Comment: Now the question has been edited, to any future viewers, the OP originally wanted this in python

Comment: You also have to try something, not only ask question!

Comment: We can also note that `N(i)` is given by `(3**(i-1)-(-1)**i)/2` and not worry about looping.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 1
b = 1
while b < p:
    c = 2 * b + 3 * a
    a = b
    b = c
return a
```

The Fortran equivalent is:

```
function fct(p) result(a)
  integer, intent(in) :: p
  integer :: a, b, c

  a = 1
  b = 1
  do while (b < p)
      c = 2 * b + 3 * a
      a = b
      b = c
  enddo
end function

program test
  integer :: fct
  external fct
  print *,fct(90)
end program
```

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen OP is going to translate it into Fortran - I don't think Fortran can do that.

Comment: I added the Fortran code... Feel free to edit or roll back if you don't like it ;-)

Comment: @Alexander Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the sequence in a variable `lst`, and `p` set,

```
max(filter(lambda x:x<=p, lst))
```

Comment: He merely has a sequence and a formula to generate the next element, so no variable `lst`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_last_element(p):
    n1 = 1
    n2 = 1
    while True:
        if n2 > p:
            return n1
        n1, n2 = n2, 2*n2 + 3 * n1

print(get_last_element(90))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a piece of code in Fortran 2003. I defined a type which has memory for two last parts of the sequence.The procedure is a recursive function. The type can be used standalone to get n-th part of the sequence or efficiently placed in a loop to find parts in a row (not necessarily beginning at 1) as it has memory of previous parts. (compiler: gfortran 4.8).

The type is defined in mymod.f90 file as

```
module mymod
    implicit none

    type  seq_t
        integer :: saved_i = 0, saved_val_i = 0, saved_val_i_1 = 0
    contains
        procedure :: getpart => getpart_seq
    end type    

contains

recursive function getpart_seq(this,i) result(r)
    class(seq_t) :: this
    integer, intent(in) :: i
    integer :: r,r_1,r_2

    if (i.eq.1.or.i.eq.2) then
        r = 1
    elseif(i.eq.this%saved_i) then
        r = this%saved_val_i
    elseif(i.eq.this%saved_i-1) then
        r = this%saved_val_i_1
    else
        r_1 = this%getpart(i-1)
        r_2 = this%getpart(i-2)
        r = 2*r_1 + 3*r_2
        this%saved_val_i_1 = r_1           
    end if
    this%saved_i = i
    this%saved_val_i = r  

end function getpart_seq

end module mymod
```

The main program for the requested case is

```
program main
    use mymod
    implicit none
    type (seq_t) :: seq
    integer :: i,p,tmp_new,tmp_old,ans

! Set the threshold here 
    p = 90
! loop over parts of the sequence    
    i = 0
    do
        i = i + 1
        tmp_new = seq%getpart(i)
        print*,tmp_new
        if (tmp_new>p) then
            ans = tmp_old
            exit
        end if    
        tmp_old = tmp_new
    end do    
    print*,"The last part of sequence less then",p," is equal to",ans
end program
```

The outcome is

```
1
1
5
13
41
121
The last part of sequence less then          90  is equal to          41.
```